# Saving input file into another folder in php

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am beginner with php.

I found out that the best tool to work with MySQL database and files is php.

So I need to get file from 'file_name'

```
<input type=file name="file_name">
```

and to save this file into another place. For example at d:/folder/

Tell me please how can I do it in php. Or there is another way to solve this issue

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509333/how-to-upload-save-files-with-desired-name

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673393/php-file-upload)

Comment: Just an extra note, this site is useful if your new to php: http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$target_dir = "uploads/"; // folder path
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["file_name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

follow this tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in html form tag. Otherwise you won't get $_FILE arr