# php flie upload error

Tags: php, html

I have an error. I made an file upload in HTML 5 and PHP. When I try to upload anything there always appears an error. Here's the code:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload your file" name="submit">
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
$target_path = "upload/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been                                    uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you initially define `$target_file` that is used in the `if( file_exists( $target_file ) ){` ? I think you need to use `$target_path` in there! Also, you should include the error in your question rather than just "there's always an error"

Comment: Please follow the link i hope it will useful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673393/php-file-upload

Comment: Just change the filename in the target portion of the move_uploaded_file call  
`if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Maybe is't about my server on RPI, but I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the variable used in the logic test was not defined anywhere. I believe you were intending something like this.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload your file" name="submit">
</form>
<?php

    $target_path = "upload/";
    $target_file = $target_path . basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] );

    if( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {

        if ( file_exists( $target_file ) ) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file ) ) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] ). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the **filename** in the target portion of the **move_uploaded_file** call

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Maybe is't about my server on RPI, but I don't think so.