# <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"> save image to database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mobile web app form where I access the mobile device camera and capture a photo along with some other details captured within other fields in the form. Using php I save the information captured in the form to a mysql database sucessfully, but the image is not stored. I have searched for a resolution but cannot find anything on using php with

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

to store the image in a database. The database field is currently blob but this can change if needed.

The form works perfectly for all other data, so the issue is with my lack of understanding of how to handle images or files with php. can anyone help or point me in the right direction please. The basis of my code is pasted below.

The form save is working fine as the bus_name input saves to the database, but the bus_img record is blank.

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="view_record">
  <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn  ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-back">Back</a>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="saveRecord.php">
      <label for="bus_name">Business Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="bus_name" id="bus_name" placeholder="Enter Business Name">

      <label for="bus_type">Business Type:</label>
      <input type="text" name="bus_type" id="bus_type" placeholder="Enter Business Type">

      <label for="bus_tel">Business Tel:</label>
      <input type="text" name="bus_tel" id="bus_tel" placeholder="Enter Business Tel No">

      <label for="bus_img">Business Photo:</label>
      <input type="file" name="bus_img" id="bus_img" accept="image/*;capture=camera">

      <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Enter Comments"></textarea>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$bus_img = $bus_name = "";

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$conn) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());}   

    $bus_img = $_FILES["bus_img"];
    $bus_img = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $bus_img);
    $bus_name = $_POST["bus_name"]; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblLead(leadImage, occupantName)

    VALUES ('$bus_img','$bus_name')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {       
    } else 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . mysqli_error($conn);
    }   
    mysqli_close($conn);
    exit();     
}
?>
```

ANy help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not to be rude, but if you couldn't find _anything_ on how to store images using PHP, then you didn't really do much searching.

Comment: search this in stackoverflow      <input type=“file” accept=“image/*;capture=camera”> save image to database using php

Comment: Where do you have the upload JS which puts ur image to some directory? If you have it check whether image is uploading or not.. If it is uploading then we can help further to take u to close this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673393/php-file-upload)

Comment: I am not experienced in js or php for that matter but can get by hence the call for a steer...I have no js - could you explain the steps I need to take in pseudocode please or point me to a tutorial - I clearly have some learning to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, file handling requires `$_FILES` and not `$_POST`.

Your form tag does not contain a proper enctype to handle files.

As per the manual's example on files handling:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
```

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Then you need to escape that (file) data and there are a few ways to do this.

One of which being `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $file)`

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Something you should also be using against all your data as it is presently open to an SQL injection.

I.e. and by replacing:

```
$bus_img = $_POST["bus_img"];
```

with:

```
$bus_img = $_FILES["bus_img"];
$bus_img = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $bus_img);
```

And make sure that the file does not exceed the maximum uploaded size allowed/set on your server.

Use proper error checking also.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Thanks, I have made the proposed amendments to my code (amended in the post as well), tested with no success - what is the reference made above to uploading the file - do I need to do this first, so save file to a folder on my device? I will add all the error handling etc. later once I get the file handling part working - I understand this, right to point out though :-)

Comment: sorry, need to read the reference you posted on file upload - will get reading now